# Programmatically Remove Shipping tax on checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shipping-tax

Hello I wish to remove shipping tax from the quote programmatically under specific condition.So please give me idea how to remove it.

Comment: Are you asking how to prevent the 'Shipping & Tax' from displaying? Or, are you trying to modify the final price?

Comment: To modify the final price

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to simply remove the 'Estimate Shipping and Tax' block dynamically, then you can do so from

```
app/design/frontend/default/Your_Theme/template/checkout/cart.phtml
```

Find the line of code which looks like

```
<?php if (!$this->getIsVirtual()): echo $this->getChildHtml('shipping'); endif; ?>
```

and replace it with something like

```
<?php if (!$this->getIsVirtual() && $conditionIsTrue):
    echo $this->getChildHtml('shipping');
endif; ?>
```

Comment: I mean to change the shipping amount on checkout

Answer (score 1):

Hi i have made custom module & use below  event to remove the shipping rate from grand total

```
    <sales_quote_address_collect_totals_after > 
             <observers >
                  <kinex_order >
                       <class > < kinex_order > <class> / observer>
                       <method > setShippingCost </method>
                   </kinex_order >
                 </observers>

         </sales_quote_address_collect_totals_after >
```

```
public function setShippingCost(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
       $events=$observer->getEvent();
        $address=$events->getQuoteAddress();
        if($address->getAddressType()=='shipping'){

     //echo $address->removeAllShippingRates();
        // exit;

     //$address->setShippingAmount(0);
      $samount=  $address->getShippingAmount();
     $address->getSubtotalInclTax();
     $gt= $address->getGrandTotal();
     $total=$gt-$samount;
     $address->setGrandTotal($total);
    $address->removeAllShippingRates();

    //print_r($rates);

        //$address->setCollectShippingRates(true);
        }


    }
```

Comment: This removes shipping cost from everything, with no conditional logic as per the OP's question.

Comment: Using template file only  block the shipping at frontend level but in quote object   shipping will be added

Comment: What If I want to change the amount?